# System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument Is Slow

Tags: c#, printing, reporting-services

I have a application that needs to print a Metafile.  The Metafile is a rendering of a SSRS report.  I am using the System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument class to print the report.  Here is the my class that is doing the printing:

```
public class EMFPrinter
{
    private IList<Stream> m_streams;
    private string printerName;
    private int m_currentPageIndex;

    public EMFPrinter(IList<Stream> reportstreams, string printer)
    {
        m_streams = reportstreams;
        printerName = printer;
        m_currentPageIndex = 0;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        printDoc.Print();
    }

    private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, ev.PageBounds);
        m_currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
    }
}
```

If I run this from my desktop (Windows 8) it runs great.  If I try to run it from the server that it needs to run on (Windows Server 2008 R2) it works great for some printers, however the printer that I need it to print on is a HP LaserJet 1536dnf, and when I try to print to it from the server it literally takes about five minutes to print.  If I try to print to that same printer from my desktop it prints immediately.  If I try to print to that printer from the server from some application (like paint) then it prints immediately.

What could be causing my code to take so long to print to this printer from the server?

Comment: Is it possible that the 1536 is just not powerful enough and the report you are printing is complex?  Can you output to file?  How large is the output file?  The report output might be very inefficient and a more 'business' style printer might handle it better due to processor etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a print driver issue.  After fighting with this for awhile I downloaded the latest print driver and installed it on the server.  I then installed the printer on the server using the new print driver and setting it up as a local printer with a ip address port.  This fixed the issue.